# Materialize to validate dynamic checkboxes

Tags: angular, materialize

I have a list of checkboxes returning from Springboot service and mapped this way in angular.
I'm using materialize design.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 60px;">

    <h1>Atender Ticket {{ ticket.id }}</h1>
    <div [hidden]="submitted">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Título</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.titulo }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Status</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.status }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Aplicação</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.aplicacao.nome }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Erro</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.erro.nome }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Data de Abertura</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.dtAbertura | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Data de Modificação</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.dtModificacao | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Usuario de Abertura</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.usuarioAbertura.nome }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <label for="disabled">Usuario de Atendimento</label>
                <input required disabled value="{{ ticket.usuarioAtendimento.nome }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <label for="disabled">Descrição</label>
                <textarea required disabled value="{{ ticket.usuarioAtendimento.nome }}" id="disabled" type="text" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
<div class="col s12">
    <h4>Pendencias</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pendencia of ticket.pendencias">
               <input type='checkbox' id="pendencia{{pendencia.id}}" validate="true" required="true" [checked]="pendencia.checked"><label for="pendencia{{pendencia.id}}"> {{pendencia.nome}}</label>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>

        </div>



            <div class="input-field">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" [hidden]="!submitted">
        <h4>Registro submetido com sucesso!</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the piece I want to validade:

```
<div class="col s12">
    <h4>Pendencias</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pendencia of ticket.pendencias">
               <input type='checkbox' id="pendencia{{pendencia.id}}" validate="true" required="true" [checked]="pendencia.checked"><label for="pendencia{{pendencia.id}}"> {{pendencia.nome}}</label>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
```

I want to validate in the screen and let the user to submit the form only when all checkboxes are checked.

Tried this with no success:

```
validate="true" required="true"
```

I was looking for a solution to when the user clicks on "submit" button the field will become red and some message saying "field is required" will be displayed.

Is it possible to do in a simple way?

Comment: Your html is missing the `<form>` openning tag

Comment: I pasted just the piece of the form I want to validade, but there's more. The opening tag is  fine.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, the html must be valid.

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: You have multiple elements using the same ID. IDs have to be unique